# SQL Lite Vs. SQLServer 2008R2

Tags: android, performance, android-sqlite

I have recently started working with Android. I decided to create a small personal android app for myself and my friends (anyone who wish to use it.) It’s a fitness tracking app where it’ll store number of sets and repetitions that you do for the day. Then, you can view your daily, weekly, or monthly progress.  I have a WCF Web service that is communicating with SQL server database.  However, I was wondering if will be better to use SQL Lite.  I was thinking the app will be lighter using the web service, I could control the database, and I could even add more features that would allow folks to share their report with other friends. However, I have to host the web service, it will cost money, and if the service is down, the entire app is down.
Since I am a novice, I’d like to know what other cost/benefit that I should take into consideration?

Comment: android devices come inbuilt with sqlite , and the method @Boardy said is good for a non-commercial app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to host the database on your own server via a web service.

I think the easiest and cheapest method would be store the data in the embedded sqlite database which is local to the device. Then to ensure it is available on multiple devices, export the data from the database in some way, xml file, csv etc and upload this file to a cloud service such as drop box or Google Drive.

Then the app can use the file from Drive or Dropbox to sync the data into the local device database.

Answer (score 1):

Start small and go big.

First implement it using sqlite on the phone and release it with adds or a paid version.
Once you see enough growth in fame and popularity and start seeing income, you can switch to the server, and go big.

I do not see any need to spend money on something which you yourself are not sure will be popular.

Also as you grow servers will start getting more expensive, and you will have to take into consideration emergency measures and such. That is why it is better to have something small and working and build upon it, rather than try something big and stop due to it taking up too much time or being costly.

Comment: np, I have done that mistake myself, and have abandoned a really good app idea due to frustration. So by seeing feedback from people you will know whether to expand or not.